# Why segfaults occur with string.h functions?

Tags: c

With the same command in my coworker's PC, my program works without the problem.
But in my PC, the program crashes with segfault;

GDB backtrace at core reads as follows:

```
#0 strrchr () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strrchr.S:32
32     ../sysdeps/x86_64/strrchr.S: no such file or directory
(gdb) bt
#0 strrchr () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strrchr.S:32
#1 0x00007f10961236d7 in dirname (path=0x324a47a0 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x324a47a0>) at dirname.c:31
```

I'm already compiling the executable with -g -ggdb options.

Odd thing is that.. with valgrind the program works without error in my PC as well.

How can I solve the problem? I've observed that the errors occur only with strrchr, strcmp, strlen, ... string.h functions.

+Edit: the gdb backtrace indicates that the program crashes here:

```
char* base_dir = dirname(get_abs_name(test_dir));
```

where get_abs_name is defined as

```
char* get_abs_name(char* dir) {
    char abs_path[PATH_MAX];
    char* c = malloc(PATH_MAX*sizeof(char));
    realpath(dir, abs_path);
    strcpy(c, abs_path);
    return c;
}
```

+Edit2: 'dir' is a path of certain file, like '../program/blabla.jpg'.

Using valgrind,

```
printf("%s\n", dir)
```

normally prints '/home/frozenca/path_to_program'.
I can't guess why the program crashes without valgrind..

Comment: You have a bug in your program. Most probably some buffer overflow. Post the code to get useful answers.

Comment: So you want us to fix your code without seeing the code. Well. .

Comment: I believe if the strings are not null terminated than it will cause problems, hence best is to pass length of the string and use num of character based APIs like strncmp, strncpy, etc.

Comment: @spectras  I've uploaded the code now..

Comment: Please study the concept of a [mcve] and read [ask].

Comment: One thing that stands out is that there is no error checking in your code.

Comment: The error occurs in strchr/strcmp/strlen/etc. not because there is an error on those functions, but because your own code calls these functions(directly or indirectly) in a way you are not supposed to. You need to check that realpath() succeeds - since you didn't check for errors here, perhaps there's other important places you forgot to check and catch a real error. You also need to inspect the `dir` argument to your function to verify it contains what you think it should contain(and show us what it contains).

Comment: @frozenca> what is the value of `test_dir`, and what is the full name of the directory you run your program from?

Comment: also, why do you need the local `abs_path` buffer? You can write to `c` directly avoiding the `strcpy`.

Comment: @MathieuBorderé>  Actually even more than this, assuming either POSIX 2008 or GNU libc, you can just use `NULL` for the buffer and let it allocate the correct size for you.

Comment: @spectras I was just about to edit my comment to include that info :) So basically that function is a wrapper around `realpath` and is useless (and buggy).

Comment: Not realated to the problem, but your call to` dirname` leaks the path. You need to `free` the path returned by `get_abs_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot know for sure without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code looks mostly correct (albeit convoluted), except you do not check for errors.

```
char* get_abs_name(char* dir) {
    char abs_path[PATH_MAX];
    char* c = malloc(PATH_MAX*sizeof(char));  /* this may return NULL */
    realpath(dir, abs_path);                  /* this may return NULL */
    strcpy(c, abs_path);
    return c;
}
```

Now, how could this lead to an error like you see? Well, if `malloc` returns NULL, you'll get a crash right away in `strcpy`. But if `realpath` fails:

- The content of `abs_path` remains undefined.
- So `strcpy(c, abs_path)` will copy undefined content. Which could lead to it copying just one byte if `abs_path[0]` happens to be `\0`. But could also lead to massive heap corruption. Which happens depends on unrelated conditions, such as how the program is compiled, and *whether some debugging tool such as valgrind is attached*.

TL;DR: get into the habit of checking every function that may fail.

```
char* get_abs_name(char* dir) {
    char abs_path[PATH_MAX];
    char* c = malloc(PATH_MAX*sizeof(char));
    if (!c) { return NULL; }
    if (!realpath(dir, abs_path)) {
        free(c);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(c, abs_path);
    return c;
}
```

Or, here, you can simplify it alot assuming a GNU system or POSIX.1-2008 system:

```
char * get_abs_name(const char * dir) {
    return realpath(dir, NULL);
}
```

Note however that either way, in your main program, you also **must** check that `get_abs_name()` did not return NULL, otherwise `dirname()` will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Drop your function entirely and use the return value of `realpath(dir, NULL)` instead.

Answer (score -3):

Convert type

```
char* c = malloc(PATH_MAX*sizeof(char));
```

Thanks!